# A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sqlite, dart

I am not use sqflite in my project. but message throw

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\omor\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\sqflite-2.2.8\android\build.gradle' line: 32
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':sqflite'.

> No signature of method: build_2b5nv2gppswbcwhvgd3rrj7jc.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_2b5nv2gppswbcwhvgd3rrj7jc$_run_closure3) values: [build_2b5nv2gppswbcwhvgd3rrj7jc$_run_closure3@e2eb4ec]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 463
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am not use sqflite in my project. but message throw

Comment: Did you use 'flutter clean' and 'flutter pub get' ?

Comment: Any solution to it? facing the same issue after updating my packages

Answer (score 0):

in pubspec.yaml
use `sqflite: 2.2.6` instead of `sqflite: ^2.2.8`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think adding namespace in 2.2.8 broke old android applications (i.e. generated with earlier flutter sdk version). Can you try to update sqflite to 2.2.8+1 - which adds a fix when namespace are not supported - or follow the gradle migration guide: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-java-gradle-migration-guide